# How can I use OptionParser to print to the command line?

Tags: python, command-line, optionparser

I'd like to use option parser to print the result of a computation to the command line.  So far, I have

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-s','--some', help = "Print some of the Suspects")
parser.add_option('-a','--all',help = "Print all of the Suspects")

(opts,args) = parser.parse_args()
```

If the user passes `-s`, I would like the first 25 rows of a dataframe to be printed (I know how to do this).  If `-a` is passed, I would like the entire dataframe to be printed. What do I have left to do?

Comment: `optparse` is deprecated in favour of `argparse`. And what do you have left to do? Write your program to print your dataframes of course. Can you be a bit more specific as of why you have a problem with parsing arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-s','--some', help = "Print some of the Suspects")
parser.add_option('-a','--all',help = "Print all of the Suspects")

(opts,args) = parser.parse_args()

if opts.some:
    print "some results"
if opts.all:
    print "all results"
```